# iOS how to connect specific WiFi SSID with minimum user interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, wifi, ssid

I have to iphone applications that they use two different networks. Changing network setting for each application is not user friendly. I want to do such thing as follows,

When application starts, it checks the availability of particular network (SSID) and popup a message to the user to permit to connect. Once user click on "OK" they it connect to that particular network.

Anybody has similar experience ?
How can I connect to given SSID using objectiveC ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading for a solution to achieve app controlled networking, but it seems impossible without the use of `Apple80211` private API.

The best i think you can do is with [CaptiveNetwork](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html).

With this you can register a list of SSID's for your device and it will suppress web sheet.

From the doc:

`By calling the CNSetSupportedSSIDs function, an application can register a list of wireless network SSIDs with Captive Network Support, thereby assuming responsibility for authenticating with those networks. Typically when a user joins a captive network, Captive Network Support provides a web sheet that allows the user to authenticate with the network. If an application has registered the SSID of the captive network, however, the web sheet is suppressed, and the user can complete authentication in the appropriate application.`